# Do a 'soft-refresh' (only JS and CSS) of a WebSocket/AJAX application

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am developing an application using websockets, with a fallback on ajax.

Most of the logic resides on the client side of the application, models, views, etc.

While developing I often need to make minor changes, and do a refresh. The way I do this is by a hard browser refresh, which basically restarts the whole application.

This can take some time, these are the steps:

- get the index.html from the server
- index.html loads all the javascript files
- javascript creates the app and starts the websocket
- on succesfull websocket connection the server will send the init data
- the init data from the server is recieved by the client and the page is generated

In a normal situation this will be ok, because as soon as the app is loaded, there is no more refresh.

But this get's painfull while developing, so I thought of the following solution:

After I made my CSS changes, I run the following script:

```
softreset: function(){
    var queryString = '?reload=' + new Date().getTime();
    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function () {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, queryString);
    });
}
```

This resets all the CSS instantly, so I do not need to do a complete refresh. One step out the way.

Often times this is not enough, I also need new content, so I want to do the following:

*question*

- I need to unload all the JS files on the page, except for the one that holds the websocket connection.
- All the DOM elements, Objects, Events that are associated with these files need to be removed to.
- I need to get the new JS files from the server.
- Load them into the page, and fire the onload action

I tried working with the snippet I use for CSS, but it does not do the same trick. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Take a look at [Vogue](http://aboutcode.net/vogue/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think [live.js](http://livejs.com/) may match your require partly

Comment: Looks pretty nice. I will look and see if I can use this.